# Code coverage for Xamarin iOS mobile application for unit tests written using NUnit

Tags: macos, visual-studio, unit-testing, xamarin.ios, nunit

We have written unit tests for a Xamarin iOS native mobile application with NUnit framework available in Visual Studio for Mac. These unit tests run on iOS simulators and are passing. But the IDE doesn't provide a coverage report.

Please suggest a tool or way to get coverage report for Xamarin iOS native mobile application.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT It seems that App Center provides option for UI Testing and not unit testing the app.

Comment: Yes, you are right . It is regrettable it not contain unit test .

Comment: You can use the [vsmac-codecoverage](https://github.com/ademanuele/VSMac-CodeCoverage) extension

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately** ,now there is no way to get coverage report for Xamarin iOS by using **NUnit** in current version of [*Visual Studio for Mac*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/touch.unit#setting-up-a-test-project-in-visual-studio-for-mac).I think it will exist in the future version of *Visual Studio for Mac* .

If not mind other ways to test your application, you can have a look at App Center with [Test reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/test-reports) inside it .However it not contains unit test ,it's regrettable .